# Is it possible to execute keys/commands in select mode?

Tags: command, select-mode

By keys I mean like being `Normal` mode and pressing `e` (takes you to end of [next] word), by commands I mean like being in `Normal` mode and pressing `Shift+;` and typing `:delete`.

For example: after entering select mode, I would like to be able to press `Ctrl+e` to jump to the end of the line, selecting everything in between as I go, the equivalent of being in `Visual mode` and pressing: `Shift+$`. Is there something I can put in my `.vim` file that would make that work ? I tried this:

`snoremap <C-e> <S-$>`
and
`snoremap <C-e> execute "visual! <S-$>"`

but they both don't work. The first one replaces the selection with a `$` in the text and the second one replace the selection with `visual! $`.

Or for example copying the selection, the equivalent of being in `Visual mode` and pressing `y`. I tried: `snoremap <C-c> y`, but this just replaces the selection with a `y`.

---

**Intent behind this**

I kinda of just want to use select mode to perform selections like in normal (GUI) editors, be able to select text with `Arrow` and `Alt+Arrow`, but also with `Ctrl+[a|e]` for jumping to front/end of line and then be able to copy/delete/move/duplicate-up/down the selection, but then also just be able to start typing replace the selection. Ik you can just basically do all that with Visual mode but to replace the selection there's an extra step involved, which is first delete the selection and enter insert mode, then start typing.

Comment: Much better. I am kind of wondering why you want to treat Select like Visual rather than just using Visual. Select's primary reason for being is to emulate GUI selections. So if you type anything when text is select it will be replaced. Trying to subvert that seems like a path to disappointment. ;)   Welcome to Vi&Vim SE, BTW. (I don't mean that ironically. :)

Comment: By the way, if this can't be done, I guess it's fine, I'll stick to `Visual mode`. It's just out of curiosity, maybe someone experienced could quickly say if it's possible.

Comment: "An extra step"--meet `c`, your new friend :) (`:help v_c` says "Delete the highlighted text and start insert")

Comment: I'm glad this question was posted. I’m a vim user who prefers some things about emacs and this is a good example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By keys I mean like being Normal mode and pressing `e` (takes you to end of [next] word), by commands I mean like being in Normal mode and pressing `Shift+;` and typing `:delete`.

Yes. From Select mode, you can use [`CTRL-O`](https://vimhelp.org/visual.txt.html#v_CTRL-O) to switch to Visual mode for the duration of a single command.

So you can use `<C-o>e` to select until the end of the word, or `<C-o>:delete<CR>` to delete the lines spanning the selection. (The latter appears as `:'<,'>delete`, since `:` from Visual mode will automatically default to these bounds.)

> After entering select mode, I would like to be able to press `Ctrl+e` to jump to the end of the line, selecting everything in between as I go, the equivalent of being in Visual mode and pressing: `Shift+$`. Is there something I can put in my vimrc file that would make that work?

Yes, you can use the following mapping:

```
snoremap <C-e> <C-o>$
```

And if you want one for the beginning of the line:

```
snoremap <C-a> <C-o>^
```

Or perhaps:

```
snoremap <C-a> <C-o>0
```

Depending on which definition you like best.

> Or for example copying the selection, the equivalent of being in Visual mode and pressing `y`.

Same idea:

```
snoremap <C-c> <C-o>y
```

Comment: Somewhere out there there must be a plugin that provides this. Hopefully I'll discover where that is one day